# Make: dynamic file recursion?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have the following directory structure, with a root-node:

```
/root/
  Makefile
  branch1/
  branch2/
  .../
```

And I write the following minimal makefile:

```
branches=$(shell find * -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f "}

%:
    -${MAKE} ${MAKECMDGOALS} -C branch1
    -${MAKE} ${MAKECMDGOALS} -C branch2
    ...
```

Having prepared to dynamically perform this relay with the `branches` variable and having tried several wild-card and descendant rule variations without success, my question amounts to: how do I capture **any** command goal from outer scope (like I am doing now), and perform the make relay for each of the files my `find` expression detects?

In pseudo code (did not work with my version of `make`, which is the latest greatest available on Cygwin):

```
branches=$(shell find * -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f "}

branch-%:
    -${MAKE} ${MAKECMDGOALS} -C $*

%: ${foreach branch,${branches}, branch-${branch}}
```

Unlike the original makefile, this does not work. However, it seems like it should. Is there a way to do this?

#### And there is a second issue

Make's parallelism will be broken by my pseudo-code method (if it worked) with an exponential fan out using the `-j` option, whereas the first method I used will not break parallelism.

However, ideally, this makefile should be able to dynamically execute one make relay for each file in the branches list.  However, I don't currently see a way to implement this dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure why you're using a complex `shell` function; why not just:

```
branches := $(wildcard */.)
```

Or, if you don't want the `/.` at the end:

```
branches := $(patsubst %/.,%,$(wildcard */.))
```

Second, the reason your second attempt doesn't work is that it's not valid to create a pattern rule with no recipe.  See [Canceling Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

Instead, you can use the `.DEFAULT` special target.  It would look something like this:

```
branch-%:
        -${MAKE} -C $* $(CMD)

.DEFAULT:
        @$(MAKE) CMD=$@ ${addprefix branch-,${branches}}
```

This does use recursive make and it behaves slightly differently than your original.

I'm not sure I understand your second point about `-j`.  GNU make (unless you're using a truly old version) can communicate among all the submakes to ensure they are starting as many, but not more, jobs than you requested.

Oh, I forgot, there's another obvious way to do it if you don't want to use `.DEFAULT` and recursion:

```
$(MAKECMDGOALS): $(addprefix branch-,$branches))
```

Comment: can you explain the last one a bit more? why does that cause makefiles inside the branch folders to be executed?

Comment: Well, you have to also include the pattern rule.  That's just a replacement for the `.DEFAULT:` target, not for the entire rest of the makefile.

Comment: hey man, you are the foremost expert on make on here that I know of.  I am a huge make user and like to use it for rapid-prototyping of interactive systems and automation.  However, I have reservations around productionalizing with make.  Do you have any opinions about make as an automation system?

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to productize builds using make.  Thousands, even hundreds of thousands, of build systems have done so at all different levels of professionalism.  On the other hand, it's not always the best answer.  For example if you want to support users with project-based IDE systems you may prefer CMake which can generate project files for Xcode, Visual Studio, etc. and abstracts away some of the target-specific issues with build systems.  Only you can decide what you need.